# Microsoft ProjectOxford Vision API ClientException Error

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, vision

I am looking into the MS's new API and I am getting errors while following the tutorials.
This is my full code. I am trying to get color of images with this.
the return I am getting is "Error Return CV" so I am not getting null imageStream
nor analysisResult. 
Thank you in advance!

```
   namespace UWPApp1
{
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
     IRandomAccessStream imageStream;

    const string APIKEY_CV = [MyComputerVisionKeyComesHere];
    VisionServiceClient VisionClient = new VisionServiceClient(APIKEY_CV);
    AnalysisResult analysisResult;

    public MainPage()
    {
      this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
          FileSavePicker fileSavePicker = new FileSavePicker();
            fileSavePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            fileSavePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPEG files", new List<string>() { ".jpg" });
            fileSavePicker.SuggestedFileName = "image";

            var outputFile = await fileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

            if (outputFile == null)
            {
                // The user cancelled the picking operation
                return;
            }

            imageStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

              BitmapImage imageTest = new BitmapImage();
              imageTest.SetSource(imageStream);

            image.Source = imageTest;
                       }
        catch {
            textBox.Text = "Error taking photo";
        }
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
         VisualFeature[] feature = new VisualFeature[] { VisualFeature.Tags, VisualFeature.Description, VisualFeature.Color };
           analysisResult = await VisionClient.AnalyzeImageAsync(imageStream.AsStream(), feature);

            if (analysisResult != null)
            {
                   var color = analysisResult.Color;
                   textBox.Text = "The Accent Color is" + color.AccentColor;

            }
            else {
                textBox.Text = "analysisResult is null";
            }

        }
        catch {
            textBox.Text = "Error Return CV";
        }
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Project oxford vision API ocr exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526090/project-oxford-vision-api-ocr-exception)

I solved same way. 
I added imageStream.Seek(0); in my code